# Acumatica - Trying to copy the logic of TYPE field

Tags: c#, acumatica

I tried to copy the logic of type(field) of acumatica. I want to reset all the fields when i change the type, I don't know if I missed any configuraion in aspx and But it gives me this error "Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Reference Nbr.: Error: 'Reference Nbr.' cannot be found in the system."

Here is my code:

DAC:

```
#region Type
    public abstract class type : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _Type;
    [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXDefault("Termination")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type")]
    [PXStringList(
        new string[] { "Termination", "Repossession", "Pretermination" },
        new string[] { "Termination", "Repossession", "Pretermination" })]
    public virtual string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Type;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Type = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
#region ReferenceNbr
    public abstract class referenceNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _ReferenceNbr;
    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true,
                     InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reference Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, TabOrder = 1)]
    [PXSelector(
        typeof(Search<Termination.referenceNbr,Where<Termination.terminateType,Equal<Current<Termination.terminateType>>>>),
        typeof(Termination.referenceNbr),
        typeof(Termination.status),
        typeof(Termination.terminateType),
        typeof(Termination.loanCD),
        typeof(Termination.customerName),
        typeof(Termination.customerLocation),
        typeof(Termination.branchCD),
        typeof(Termination.reasonCode),
        typeof(Termination.description), Filterable = true, IsPrimaryViewCompatible = true)]
    [AutoNumber(typeof(LSSetup.terminationNumSeqID), typeof(Termination.dateCreated))]
    public virtual string ReferenceNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ReferenceNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ReferenceNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

ASPX(SCREEN):

```
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" runat="Server">
<px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100"
    Width="100%" DataMember="Terminations" TabIndex="1500" NoteIndicator="True"
    FilesIndicator="True" ActivityIndicator="True" ActivityField="NoteActivity"
    LinkIndicator="True" NotifyIndicator="True" DefaultControlID="edType">
    <Template>
        <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" ControlSize="S" LabelsWidth="S" StartColumn="True">
        </px:PXLayoutRule>
        <px:PXDropDown ID="edType" runat="server" DataField="Type">
        </px:PXDropDown>
        <px:PXSelector ID="edReferenceNbr" runat="server" DataField="ReferenceNbr">
        </px:PXSelector>
        <px:PXCheckBox runat="server" Text="IsHold" DataField="IsHold" AlreadyLocalized="False" ID="edIsHold" CommitChanges="True">
        </px:PXCheckBox>
        <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="Status" AlreadyLocalized="False" ID="edStatus" Enabled="False" CommitChanges="True" DefaultLocale="">
        </px:PXTextEdit>
        <px:PXDateTimeEdit runat="server" DataField="DateCreated" AlreadyLocalized="False" ID="edDateCreated" DefaultLocale="">
        </px:PXDateTimeEdit>
        <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ControlSize="XM" LabelsWidth="SM" StartColumn="True">
        </px:PXLayoutRule>
        <px:PXSelector ID="edLoanCD" runat="server" CommitChanges="True" DataField="LoanCD">
        </px:PXSelector>
        <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="CustomerName" AlreadyLocalized="False" ID="edCustomerName" CommitChanges="True" Enabled="False" DefaultLocale="">
        </px:PXTextEdit>
        <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="CustomerLocation" AlreadyLocalized="False" ID="edCustomerLocation" Enabled="False" CommitChanges="True" DefaultLocale="">
        </px:PXTextEdit>
        <px:PXSelector ID="edFinancingCompany" runat="server" DataField="FinancingCompany" Enabled="False">
        </px:PXSelector>
        <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="BranchCD" AlreadyLocalized="False" ID="edBranchCD" Enabled="False" DefaultLocale="">
        </px:PXTextEdit>
        <px:PXSelector ID="edReasonCode" runat="server" DataField="ReasonCode">
        </px:PXSelector>
        <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="Description" AlreadyLocalized="False" ID="edDescription" DefaultLocale="">
        </px:PXTextEdit>
    </Template>
</px:PXFormView>
```

Comment: It sounds like the entered reference nbr is not valid. Could be the "current" field not finding a value. To confirm, try the code you have without the where condition in the selector on ReferenceNbr

Comment: Hi @Brendan. If you notice the behavior SO Invoice when the user fill up all the requirements in the screen and change the TYPE, all fields will be cleared or reset and that's exactly what i need to do. In my case when i tried to select on LoanCD(selector) i got this error "Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Reference Nbr.: Error: 'Reference Nbr.' cannot be found in the system.", I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: The clear happens because it is a key field. The error you are getting is related to the selector on that field not being able to find the value you entered. I might also recommend to use a char size 1 for your string list and not a fixed length of 15 as not all of your values for your list are length 15 which might cause you some problems. Typically your list value is different than your displayed value. I usually use intlist so i dont have to worry about letters for stored values.